# support.microsoft.com sites are not opening

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Since a few days ago, MS support pages (like https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-function-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c) break time to time and I get below error

[image]

The problem is not appearing always, just popping up time to time

I use Chrome 87.0.4280, 64 bit (it's controlled by my company, I can't update it).

The same sites always open correctly in Edge and also in Chrome in Android

Comment: Sounds something on your company’s network is to blame.  A Chrome group policy wouldn’t necessarily effect Chromium Edge. The fact Android isn’t effected further points to a group policy or specifically a Windows setting.  The error speaks volumes, despite it being https, the error is a http 400 error.  That sounds like a proxy error.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, is there any further check I can do to point my IT team to the right way for solving this issue?

Comment: "Bad Request - Request Too Long" is an error exclusive to Chrome.  Which explains the reason it's only happening with Chrome.  Have you tried to clear both your cookies and cache?  [Seems universally suggested that this error is caused by a corrupt cookie.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538926/chrome-returns-bad-request-request-too-long-when-navigating-to-local-iis-exp)

Comment: Deleting cookies seems to solve the problem! Maybe you can write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Bad Request - Request Too Long" is an error exclusive to Chrome. Which explains the reason it's only happening with Chrome. Have you tried to clear both your cookies and cache? Seems universally suggested that this error is caused by a corrupt cookie.

credit: @Ramhound